# Should something be done about frozen "main" chatroom?

Tags: discussion, chat

I have noticed that the "main" chatroom for this site has [been frozen](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/58858/2020/6/3). By the main chatroom I mean the room which was created [when the site was created](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/58858/2017/5/16) with the description "General discussion for bioinformatics.stackexchange.com".

As far as I know, the Stack Exchange chat system will still keep at least one room from freezing. (And the rooms migrated from comments and one-to-one rooms created through "start a new room with this user" do not count here.) But none of the remaining rooms has privileged position<sup>1</sup> If you look at the rooms [associated with this site](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=bioinformatics.stackexchange.com), you can see that the only room which is not frozen is [Bioinfomatics About The Coronavirus Pandemic](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/105691/bioinfomatics-about-the-coronavirus-pandemic).

So my questions are:

1. Should something be done about this? (On one hand, it is probably good for any Stack Exchange site to have a room for general discussions. On the other hand, since the room was frozen long time ago, probably it wasn't really used and nobody seems to be missing this room.)
2. What kind of action should be taken if the room is frozen again in the future?

---

<sup>1</sup>Any room can be [unfrozen by moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70198/how-do-i-unfreeze-a-frozen-chat-room). Some posts where you can find more details concerning frozen rooms:

- [Why is the main chat room frozen?](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/343)
- [Don't freeze a chatroom soon after a mod has unfrozen it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130472)
- [Main chatroom for a SE site and chatroom pruning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226302)
- [Main chat room for a newer site still freezes due to inactivity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/352769)
- A related feature request: [Exclude the main chat room from automatic freezing/deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100519)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've unfrozen the room, though it gets little enough traffic that I expect it will eventually get frozen again.

Answer (score 0):

I think its a resource for the site, not that I've used it much, but I think I  should have used it rather than create new 'chat rooms'. I think we just need to be mindful of posting a random 'chat' into the room to keep it afloat. Its a bit like the Parsees keeping their ceremonial fire alight for the last couple of thousand years. The motto is it doesn't need a practical purpose, its just a nice idea.

One of the problems with creating a chat room for a specific dialogue is that once the conversation is done, the room is frozen and permanently archived. So next time another chat room needs to be created and presumably another ... ad infinitum and it just creates clutter. Much better to centralise this for a single chat room.